# Removing spam from a MySQL db table

Tags: php, mysql, spam

I'm currently working on a PHP website I inherited. It includes a comment feature and the current comments database has a heap of spam comments in it, which the owners would like removed.

Spam comments typically include raw HTML or BBCode URLs which I am currently matching and removing (the comments don't allow for/render HTML), comments and names with the typical keywords (free, buy, coupons, loans, cialis, viagra, etc), and random nonsense, an example:

> they will cross check with Hotel.After long deliberations she fllainy
>   said that the concerned peson who did booking had leftthe hotel job
>   and now I can be given alternate hotel.I had specially booked this
>   hotel which is right on beach after paying so much money but I was
>   offeredan alternate hotel in the city of Panjim from where to reach
>   beach it takes around than 45-60 minutes and also the fun of staying
>   on beach of my family waslost.Any ways I made the compromise and
>   settled in new hotel in Panjim.But on 28th when I checked in new Hotel
>   Royal PArk Beach Resort I was stunned to see the state of so called 3
>   star hotel.The hotel was no where near the mentioned status while
>   selling the package.Hotel quality was totally low grade. It better
>   matched a 3rd class sub standard small town inn with dug up
>   entrance,cheaply done up reception area,stinking rooms &
>   bathrooms,burnt curtains,inferior furniture,ongoing contruction next
>   to my room,dilapidated bathrooms fixtures,dirty floor,dirty and humid
>   bed linens and overall bad feeling.[I have proof of all photographs]I
>   immediately informed make my trip' of state of the hotel and wanted
>   alternate hotel but make my trip' kept on telling me to wait and they
>   will look into it.Since my chlid was sick and immediately needed rest
>   I had no option but to check in at this Hotel.Simultaneously I kept on
>   calling Makemytrip for hours but tono avail.This wasted an entire
>   day.Finally I arranged a new genuine 4 Star Hotel Room Rent for which
>   was Rs. 5500/- per night( much below Rs. 7211/- for thishotel booked
>   by Make my trip).I informed MakeMy Trip on 28th Jan 2012 to cancel my
>   reservation and refund me entire money.Also sent a mail to them in
>   this regard.I am still wating for positive response from them but I am
>   least hopeful of getting it.So now I am approaching court to get my
>   dues and compensation.Arvinder

I've been doing string matches and deleting for obvious terms, but it's getting a bit tedious. If anyone has an efficient way to do this, I'd be really interested in hearing it.

Comment: how do you specifically define spam?

Comment: define what 'spam' is? There would have to be some sort of algorithm/criteria to indicate whether a row is considered 'spam' or not. then removing the rows based on that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't defined what your spam contains/is, it's hard to give a more concrete example, however I would look into having a regular expression that matches for specific keywords, patterns within the data.

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `field` REGEXP 'vigra|spam|example'
```

Edit: Also from your updated example, you could flag spam as having a certain character length:

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE `field` REGEXP 'vigra|spam|example'
OR LENGTH(`field`) > 500
... etc
```

Comment: Automatically deleting without human review based on simple keyword matching is very dangerous.  If your email filter would auto-delete emails with the word "spam" in them, you would never receive information about new anti-spam products :-)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't resist.. and that would be a problem because....  I don't need no spam about anti-spam products.

Comment: I would hope developers are smart enough to test their where condition  with a select statement first before running delete.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with one of the apps I care for.  I term people that provide junk data "clowns", and am collecting a set of rules that identify potential clowns.  The initial rule set was pretty basic (probably similar to the keywords you have now).  The set of rules has expanded over time, both based on my own observations and on tips from co-workers.

Notice I stated that I identify *potential* clowns.  Tables that may contain clown data get a column IsClown that can represent states "not checked", "potential clown", "not a clown", "is a clown".  I have an automatic process that checks all new data .  If that process matches one or more rules, the entry is flagged as a "potential clown", and a human checks the entries using a simple UI, either moving he state to "not a clown" or "is a clown".

Whether that will work for you depends on how well rules can be defined and on the quantity of data you are considering.  It works for me, so thought I would share.